# Mapping nodes' property into array in Cypress

Tags: cypress, mapping

say, we have this in the page

```
<table>
<tr specprop="A"><td>...</td></tr>
<tr specprop="B"><td>...</td></tr>
</table>
```

I would like to get back this array: **['A', 'B']**

I can get the rows by

```
cy.get('tr')
```

But I don't know how to access the 'specpro' property and produce the expected array above.

Thanks in advance.

Csaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
let arr = []
cy.get('tr').each($tr => {
    cy.wrap($tr).its('specprop').then(value => {arr.push(value)})
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do the mapping inline by using the `.map()` function.

```js
cy.get('tr')
  .then($els => Cypress.$.map($els, (tr) => tr.getAttribute('specprop')))
  .should('deep.eq', ['A', 'B'])
  .then(specProps => {
    // use value here
  })
```

or with a custom command

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('mapToAttribute', {prevSubject:true}, (subject, attribute) => {
  return Cypress.$.map(subject, (el) => el.getAttribute(attribute))
})

cy.get('tr')
  .mapToAttribute('specprop')
  .should('deep.eq', ['A', 'B'])
  .then(specProps => {
    // use value here
  })
```